# Como fazer um Pivot lambda em uma lista C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estou com uma dificuldade imensa para fazer um comando pivot em uma lista que esta vindo do banco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima o select que esta vindo com os dados.. O campo data q eu gostaria de colocar o comando pivot.

Segue minha classe:

```
public class RelatorioPrincipalModel
{
    public string CodRelatorio { get; set; }
    public string AssuntoRelatorio { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoRelatorio { get; set; }
    public string LojaRelatorio { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio01 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio02 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio03 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio04 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio05 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio06 { get; set; }
}
```

E a imagem de como deverá aparecer na pagina: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou trazendo as informações em uma lista idêntica a primeira imagem e vou adicionar os dados em outra lista com as datas na mesma linha.

Comment: Poste o código da geração da grid final... você quer fazer por c# ou pelo sql?

Comment: @MarllonNasser.. Quero fazer em C# lambda. O código final é exatamente a classe que postei.

Mas segue o codigo abaixo:
List<RelatorioDisponivelModel> lstDisponivel = new List<RelatorioDisponivelModel>();
            lstDisponivel = new RelatorioBo().RelatorioDisponivelBo(18,UsuarioLogado.IdUsuario, UsuarioLogado.Cpf);

Comment: O que você quer junta na mesmas colunas são os campos                                     `public string    LojaRelatorio { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio01 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio02 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio03 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio04 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio05 { get; set; }
    public string DataRelatorio06 { get; set; }`

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza na verdade eu quero alinhar as datas vindo do banco. Ou seja, para cada codigo, Assunto, Descrição e loja eu tenho 5 datas. E eu quero colocar em uma unica linha.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o `GroupBy` e depois um `Select` para junta sua colunas em uma unica se esse é seu proposito. .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RelatorioPrincipalModel Disponivel = new RelatorioPrincipalModel()
            {
                CodRelatorio = "Teste",
                AssuntoRelatorio = "Teste",
                DescricaoRelatorio = "Teste",
                LojaRelatorio = "Teste",
                DataRelatorio01 = "DataRelatorio01",
                DataRelatorio02 = "DataRelatorio02",
                DataRelatorio03 = "DataRelatorio03",
                DataRelatorio04 = "DataRelatorio04",
                DataRelatorio05 = "DataRelatorio05",
                DataRelatorio06 = "DataRelatorio06",
            };

            List<RelatorioPrincipalModel> lstDisponivel = new List<RelatorioPrincipalModel>();
            lstDisponivel.Add(Disponivel);

            var lista = lstDisponivel
                .GroupBy(R => new { R.CodRelatorio, R.AssuntoRelatorio, R.DescricaoRelatorio, R.LojaRelatorio })
                .Select(R => new
                {
                    CodRelatorio = R.Key.CodRelatorio,
                    AssuntoRelatorio = R.Key.AssuntoRelatorio,
                    DescricaoRelatorio = R.Key.DescricaoRelatorio,
                    LojaRelatorio = R.Key.LojaRelatorio,
                    Data = R.Select(C => C.DataRelatorio01.ToString() + " "
                    + C.DataRelatorio02.ToString() + " " + C.DataRelatorio03.ToString() + " " + C.DataRelatorio04.ToString() +
                    " " + C.DataRelatorio05.ToString() + " " + C.DataRelatorio06.ToString()).FirstOrDefault(),

                }).ToList();

        }
    }

    public class RelatorioPrincipalModel
    {
        public string CodRelatorio { get; set; }
        public string AssuntoRelatorio { get; set; }
        public string DescricaoRelatorio { get; set; }
        public string LojaRelatorio { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio01 { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio02 { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio03 { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio04 { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio05 { get; set; }
        public string DataRelatorio06 { get; set; }
    }
}
```